# Proof of concavity of Implicit Function

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have $F$ functions indexed by $f$, $m_f(\tau)$, implicitly defined by:

$$m_f(\tau) = 1 + m_f(\tau) \frac{\tau_f e^{-m_f(\tau)}}{1 + \sum_{g = 1}^{F}\tau_g e^{m_g(\tau)}}, \forall f = \{1,\ldots,F\}$$

where $\tau = \{\tau_g > 0: g \in \{1,\ldots,F\}\}.$ I need to show:
$$\frac{\partial^2 m_f}{\partial (\tau_f)^2} < 0, \forall f$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 m_f}{\partial \tau_f \partial \tau_g} < 0, \forall g \neq f$$

In case it helps, I know that $m_f(\tau)$ is well defined (there is a unique $m^f$ that solves the expression above for any $\tau$), and I know that $\frac{\partial m^f}{\partial \tau_f} > 0$, and $\frac{\partial m^f}{\partial \tau_g} < 0$.

I've tried to tackle the proof using Mathematica, but my knowledge is way too basic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something like `Reduce[D[m[[f]], tau[[f]], tau[[g]]] < 0]` — beyond that, it's going to be hard to be specific. People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful